# What am I? 'Tis the season of mutual puzzling

Tags: riddle

> I'm born when one is over the treasure spot,
>   I'm used when you drive to buy a present,
>   I'm born in the spirit of mutual gift-giving,
>   Yet I'm literally a super negative one.

Kinda short, so might be open to interpretation, but I assure you your efforts in solving this riddle will be reciprocated with a +1 from me!

Comment: Excellent riddle! And since tensions are running so high on this site, I should explain that 'lynch mob!' is a compliment between riddlers and not a threat :-)

Comment: And congrats on making it to the Hot Network Questions :-)

Comment: Why is d'alar'cop giving away so much of his reputation as bounties?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer must be

> reciprocal.

*I'm born when one is over the treasure spot,*

> *X marks the spot*; "the treasure spot" means X. So "one is over the treasure spot" means 1 over x, or $\frac{1}{x}$, the reciprocal function.

*I'm used when you drive to buy a present,*

> The internal combustion engine, present in the car you drive in, is a type of [reciprocating engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocating_engine).

*I'm born in the spirit of mutual gift-giving,*

> **Mutual** gift-giving; one person reciprocates another's gift by giving them a gift in return.

*Yet I'm literally a super negative one.*

> Another notation for the reciprocal of a number is to raise that number to the power of minus one; reciprocals can be denoted by $^{-1}$, "negative one" in superscript.

And finally...

> "Your efforts in solving this riddle will be **reciprocated** with a +1 from me!"

LYNCH MOB! :-)

If you'd like to know how I solved this, the first line always seemed to me the most tractable. I struggled with 'one' and 'X' for a while before eventually thinking of the correct interpretation, which fitted with the third line. As I was writing the answer, I realised how it fitted the fourth line too, and that was when I was certain I was right. The second line was the hardest, and required a quick search on the internet.

Soon it'll be time to post *my* seasonal riddle...

Comment: Search piston engine in wikipedia!

Comment: @McMagister - Finished now! Feedback also added :-)

Comment: Oh man I would never have got this (didn't know a combustion engine was "<that word>", for a start). So glad I cheated.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Neither did I when I found the solution! :-) It was the first line that enabled me to crack it; I had to do a bit of Googling for the second line.